How can I enter decimal numbers in a TextEdit field?
I want to be able to enter decimal numbers in a TextEdit field, but with the following method I can only enter whole numbers:
// value is an f32
let mut value_str = value.to_string();
if ui.text_edit_singleline(&mut value_str).changed() {
    if let Ok(parsed_value) = value_str.parse() {
        value = parsed_value;
    }
}

I´m using egui version 0.27.2

Can you describe the behavior? I imagine once you type a decimal point, ., it removes it / doesn't look like it accepts it?

Yes, it gets removed directly when typing

Probably because parsing e.g. "42." produces the value 42 which turns back into "42" on the next iteration.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. all code required to reproduce the problem.

DragValue
First, what you want might be a DragValue, which allow number input and draging.
ui.add(egui::DragValue::new(&mut self.f));

Input String
But if you really want a text field, you might want to set a temp buffer variable for the user input, and change the value on lost_focus
struct AppState{
    // ...
    f: f32,
    input: String,
    // ...
}

// inside show()
if ui.text_edit_singleline(&mut self.input).lost_focus() {
    // if the input value is vaild, update the value
    if let Ok(parsed_value) = self.input.parse() {
        self.f = parsed_value;
    }
    // sync the input value and the value regardless
    self.input = self.f.to_string();
}

